# Turn off anti-aliasing in Lubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, anti-aliasing, lubuntu, lxde

I have an X setup with XMing on Windows 7 as X the server and X clients (for example *lxterminal*) started on a Lubuntu 11.10 running in a VirtualBox VM. This works well, but I don't really like the smooth and blurry look of the anti-aliased fonts in my *lxterminal* windows.

I have tried to turn anti-aliasing off in *lxappearance*. It saves the settings to my .gtkrc-2.0 file:

```
...
gtk-xft-antialias=0
gtk-xft-hinting=1
gtk-xft-hintstyle="hintmedium"
gtk-xft-rgba="rgb"
...
```

But antialiasing is **not** turned off and when starting *lxappearance* **anti-aliasing is enabled** again.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

In this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570076/netbeans-forwarded-over-x11-font-problem stackoverflow question someone was asking the opposite and the answer was "Run a font server to get AntiAliasing" so you could try stopping the fontserver to disable antialiasing.

Once you've done this your fonts will be rendered by Windows and make have to turn off Window antialiasing. This I don't know how to do I'm afraid.